# System.DllNotFoundException mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, exception, dll, reference

I'm trying to develop a bot for Discord, but when trying to connect it to a Voice Channel, C# says it can't find mscorlib.dll

The part that made me ask here, is this: [image]

Basically C# can't find mscorlib.dll, but it's already referencing it... And if i try to reference it directly, it explicitly says IT'S ALREADY REFERENCING IT!
What do i do?

Comment: Can you add the bit for "C# can't find mscorlib.dll" - because it may be that that's the solvable problem here, but all we have is a rough description. (Ideally, create a [mcve])

Comment: It is the kind of problem you'll have when you target .NETCore.  Mixing the "core" and "full" versions of the framework is not possible.

Comment: You are most likely missing another dll. This is described in the error message that has lead you to attempt and add mscorlib. Maybe you can add the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What problem is that your missing a .dll that the compiler needs.

What I did to fix it use go to https://discord.foxbot.me/binaries/
Download the 32bit libsodium.dll and the opus.dll
Put it in bin/debug in your project folder

Hope it helps!